# Formalizing multiple type judgements ⊢ within the same Γ in Agda

Tags: types, agda

I'm an Agda beginner! I have read both [Programming language foundations in Agda](http://plfa.github.io/) and [Verified functional programming in Agda](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1970001240), and now I want to try to formalize a small language by myself. As I am interested in Algebraic Effects and Handlers, I started with Pretnar's tutorial ["An Introduction to Algebraic Effects and Handlers"](http://www.eff-lang.org/handlers-tutorial.pdf). Pretnar's language has 2 type judgements (Γ ⊢ values and Γ ⊢ computations) as it is usual to follow an approach close to CBPV. Also, as it is suggested in PLPA, I'm trying to use de Bruijn representation.

Some of the code I have:

```
mutual
  data ValueType : Set where
    ~ℕ      : ValueType
    ~      : ValueType
    ~⊤      : ValueType
    _⟶_    : ValueType → CompType → ValueType
    _⇒_     : CompType → CompType → ValueType

  data CompType : Set where
    _!_ : ValueType → Δ → CompType

data Type : Set where
  ⋆ : ValueType → Type
  ✪ : CompType → Type

data Context : Set where
  ∅   : Context
  _,_ : Context → Type → Context

data _∋_ : Context → Type → Set where
  Z  : ∀ {Γ A}   → Γ , A ∋ A
  S_ : ∀ {Γ A B} → Γ ∋ B → Γ , A ∋ B

mutual
  data _⊢ₖ_ : Context → CompType → Set where
  -- computation defs go here
  data _⊢ₑ_ : Context → ValueType → Set where
  -- values defs go here

data _⊢_ : Context → Type → Set where
  ~_ : ∀ {Γ A}
     → Γ ∋ A
       -----
     → Γ ⊢ A

  ⋆ : ∀ {Γ} {A : ValueType}
    → Γ ⊢ₑ A
      ------
    → Γ ⊢ ⋆ A

  ✪ : ∀ {Γ} {C : CompType}
    → Γ ⊢ₖ C
      -------
    → Γ ⊢ ✪ C
```

Then I proceed to prove renaming and substitution, which is where my problem arises: how can I prove them?

```
mutual
  renameₑ : ∀ {Γ Δ} → (∀ {A} → Γ ∋ A → Δ ∋ A) 
      → (∀ {A} → Γ ⊢ₑ A → Δ ⊢ₑ A)
  renameₖ : ∀ {Γ Δ} → (∀ {A} → Γ ∋ A → Δ ∋ A)
      → (∀ {A} → Γ ⊢ₖ A → Δ ⊢ₖ A)

rename : ∀ {Γ Δ} → (∀ {A} → Γ ∋ A → Δ ∋ A)
   → (∀ {A} → Γ ⊢ A → Δ ⊢ A)
rename ρ (~ x) = ~ (ρ x)
rename ρ (⋆ A) = {!!} (renameₑ ρ (⋆ A))
rename ρ (✪ A) = {!!} (renameₖ ρ (✪ A))
```

I can prove a `rename` for each of the judgements, but I can seem to find a way to prove the "main" rename function that unifies them. I wonder if this is a correct way to proceed, and I will just need to make my proofs come along (and if so, how?)... or is there another, better way to formalise the language I'm interested in in Agda?

Comment: Please include some code that type checks.

Comment: What if you write `rename ρ (⋆ A) = ⋆ (renameₑ ρ A)`?

Comment: @user3237465 I'm looking for a more high level answer than an actual way to get it to typecheck. but here something that typechecks https://gist.github.com/cyberglot/c4511b0799f2b16dad943d72db98abf6

Answer (score 1):

If you write

```
rename ρ (⋆ E) = {!!}
```

and look at the context in the hole, you'll see that `E` is of type `.Γ ⊢ₑ .A`. This can be readily renamed using `renameₑ`:

```
renameₑ ρ E
```

which is of type `.Δ ⊢ₑ .A` and it only remains to apply `⋆` to the result to get an `.Δ ⊢ .A`.

The basic idea is that you pattern match on a term, figure out whether it's a value or a computation, apply the corresponding renaming function and wrap the result using the same constructor. I.e. `rename` maps values to values and computations to computations, but uses different renaming functions for these judgements under the hood.

The code:

```
rename : ∀ {Γ Δ} → (∀ {A} → Γ ∋ A → Δ ∋ A)
       → (∀ {A} → Γ ⊢ A → Δ ⊢ A)
rename ρ (~ x) = ~ (ρ x)
rename ρ (⋆ E) = ⋆ (renameₑ ρ E)
rename ρ (✪ E) = ✪ (renameₖ ρ E)
```

Comment: thanks, so I can assume this is an OK way to formalize Pretnar's lang, then?

Comment: @JuGonçalves, I do not really know this language. Looks like an OK way. Also I'd use [order preserving embeddings](https://fplab.bitbucket.io/posts/2008-03-07-order-preserving-embeddin.html) for renaming.

Comment: thanks for the links, it's interesting I will try to do that :)